# Regular expression for float/double numbers

Tags: java, regex, floating-point

I've been trying to retrieve a string and 2 decimal numbers from a sentence, but the decimal part hasn't been working well.

The sentence I have is on this format: `AMBIENT_CAVE 0.5 1`
So it would be `word` (sometimes containing `_`) then 2 numbers that could be either integer (1 or 0) or a decimal between 0 and 1.

My current regular expression is: `(\w+) ([+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+) ([+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)` Which kinda works, but using the sentence example from above group 3 would be `0.`.

Results:

[image]

I only want `AMBIENT_CAVE`, `0.5` and `1`.
Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: If the integers can be only 0 or 1 and the decimal part between 0 and 1, try `(\w+)\s(?:(0(?:\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)?|1(?!\S)))\s(?:(0(?:\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)?|1(?!\S)))` see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7gbbkq/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one. Please provide more examples of available strings in order to optimize an expression

```
  (\w+)\s([\d\.]+)\s([\d\.]+)
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a `?:` to any group you don't want to capture:

```
(\w+) ([+-]?(?:[0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+) ([+-]?(?:[0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)
             ^                           ^
```